# Loading file using a path writen in edit box matlab

Tags: matlab

*hello evryone*

*wanna load file from a specific path writen in an edit box named by 'Load_text', i got the path from the edit box using :*

```
pth=get(handles.Load_text,'string');
```

*then i used 'dir' as follow:*

```
S=dir(fullfile([pth '*.bmp']));
```

*that what cause me an errur . so any ideas ?*

Comment: What was the error message?  What was the value of `pth` when you got it?  If you put a breakpoint at that location, do you get errors from `[pth '*.bmp']` or `fullfile([pth '*.bmp'])`?

Comment: the errur my friend is in the path its self since there r defrence in between ['C//...' *.bmp] and [C:/... *.bmp] that carried in the variable path, anyway thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a file then why you are using `dir`?

Since you have the file's name, then you can create the fullpath as you do with the `fullpath` method and check its existence with `exists`.

If the file exists, then you can load it with all available methods from MATLAB.

Keep in mind that this means that the file is in the same directory as your GUI files. If it is in another then you will have to add it in the `fullpath` call.

`fullpath` online doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html
`exists` online doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html

Comment: well.  i use 'Dir' to got all files names , and the meaning of using it not to upload only one file, my program allows to load a sequence of files in the same diraction also let the user to chose the direction.